# Timer in Android using ImageButton to start and Stop

Tags: android, timer

I have been working on an android programme but my timer has issues and i was trying to work on it but can not seem to get it right, any help at this moment will be highly appreciated.

My timer begins from `60 -- to 0` which is what i want. Now i was using buttons to show Start and Stop. Now i wish to use ImageButtons of Pause and Play. Please this is where i am stuck and any help again will be a good relieve i have tried looking for some info to read but didnt find.

> Just to summarize what i want to achieve
>
> 1. I want to use ImageButtons(Pause and Play) to invoke the functions, once paused the game pauses and On Play i continue

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    time= millisUntilFinished;
                    timerTextView.setText("Time Remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    timerTextView.setTextSize(10);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                    timerTextView.setText("TIMES UP");
                    timerTextView.setTextSize(10);


                }
            }.start();

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        timer.cancel();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }




    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        timer.cancel();
        ImageButton pause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pause);
        pause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ImageButton play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
        play.setVisibility((View.VISIBLE));
        EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answerField);
        input.setEnabled(false);
        timerTextView.setText("Game Paused");
    }
    public void play(View view){
        ImageButton pause= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pause);
        pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ImageButton play= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play);
        play.setVisibility((View.INVISIBLE));
        TextView outcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outcome);
        outcome.setText("");
        EditText input= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.answerField);
        input.setEnabled(true);
        CountDownTimer timer= new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                time= millisUntilFinished;
                //text1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                timerTextView.setText("Time Remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                timerTextView.setText("TIME UP");

            }

        }.start();

    }


     <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_white_18dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:onClick="play"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pause"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_pause_white_18dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:id="@+id/pause"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:onClick="pause"
            android:layout_below="@+id/questionField"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


LogCat Errors;

    view class android.widget.ImageButton with id 'play'
                at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
         Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: play [class android.view.View]
                at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
                at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
                at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4000)
                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: LogCat error? share it please

Comment: My timer doesnt start too when i use image buttons.

Comment: please clean up your code first. It is completely unclear what you are doing. E.g. why do you instantiate ImageButtons in the onClick-Event? You are re-declaring variables, code outcommented, etc.

Comment: I have cleaned up my code @Christian please assist me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the main thing that is crashing is at the time you are finding view...

If you want to declare your `Button` in `play()` you have to declare your button doing :

```
ImageButton pause= (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.pause);
```

Also with your `EditText` and `TextView`.

When you have done this, just click run on your IDE and tell me what's the problem...

Also I've read this :

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: play [class android.view.View]

Where is your Play() method called?, can you post more code?

BTW learn to clear your code, it's impossible to read/understand... if you want to people from SO even other forum, just clean up a little bit more... otherwise noone will help you.

Comment: My play method is posted above i did clear my code, sorry about, and actually i managed to get what i wanted.